# Justifying an ODE's solution

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers

In an introductory lesson into ODEs, in order to "semi-rigorously" justify the solution for e.g. : $(a)\ \ y'+y=0$ we proceed without an ansatz or guess solution (hence the "semi-rigour"):
Let: $\phi=ye^{x}$  Then by differentiating: $\phi'=y'e^{x}+ye^{x}=e^{x}(y'+y)=0$; thus: $\phi=C=\phi(0)=y_0$, therefore the final result: $y=y_0 e^{-x}$ with no direct ansatz

I tried to do the same for this ODE: $(b) \ y''+y=0$
This time with $\psi=f^{2}+f'^{2}$. So as to yield either sine or cosine for f, and WLOG end up with one of them.

I get $\psi'=2ff'+2f'f''=2f'(f+f'')$
$\Rightarrow \psi'=0 \Rightarrow \psi=C=\psi(0)$
$\rightarrow \psi(0)=f^{2} +f'^{2}$. Then I normalize f with $g(x)=f(x)/\sqrt\psi(0))$
To be formal, I tried proving that $\psi(0) \neq0$ :

$\psi(0)=0 \Rightarrow f^{2}(0)+f'^{2}(0)=0 \Rightarrow f(0)=f'(0)=0 \ \text{combined with} \ f''+f=0 \rightarrow \forall k: f^{(k)}=0 \rightarrow \text{This yields a trivial solution: the zero function which I implicitely eliminated} $ QED: $\psi(0)\neq 0$

Back to the problem: I get: $g^{2}+g'^{2}=1$, so there must: $\exists \theta:f(x)=\sqrt\psi(0)cos\theta $ This is where I couldn't justify: is the x in $g(x)$ the same as the $\theta$ in $\sin(\theta)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the ansatz should read $g(x)=ψ(0)\cosθ(x)$. But what is $ψ(0)$ doing there?

From the sum of squares you get that the point $(g(x),g'(x))$ is somewhere on the unit circle and thus at some specific angle $θ$ that depends on $x$. Which means that $g(x)=\cosθ$ and $g'(x)=\sinθ$. Assuming that the dependence $θ=θ(x)$ is differentiable, the derivative of the first equation gives $g'(x)=-\sin(θ(x))θ'(x)$ and comparing with the second equation, $θ'(x)=-1$.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I meant $f(x)=\psi(0) cos\theta(x)$. I omitted the x in $\theta(x)$ implicitly. Your input yields $\theta=-x+D$. Up till now, I didn't offer any initial conditions so as to make my proof specificity-free (wlog). How can I then get off the D? (so as to get a direct $\theta(x)$?

Comment: Yes, using trigonometric identities you get $\cos(D-x)=\cos(D)\cos(x)+\sin(D)\sin(x)$ and with the scaling factor between $g$ and $f$ you get the general solution $f(x)=c_1\cos(x)+c_2\sin(x)$.

Comment: With $c_1 =\psi(0)cos(D)=f(0),c_2=\psi(0)sin(D)=f'(0)$. Thanks!

Comment: But check your computation, if you write it up for someone else to read. There should be a square root somewhere in relation to $ψ(0)$.

Comment: Doesn't $cos(\theta)=cos(D)cos(x)+sin(D)sin(x)$ and $f(x)=\psi(0)cos(\theta)$ lead to what I meant? I tried to be careful. Maybe the square root should come from a D-less formula.

Comment: No, it is just that you chose to set $ψ(0)=f^2+f'^2$, so $f=\sqrt{ψ(0)}\cos(θ)$ and $f'=\sqrt{ψ(0)}\sin(θ)$.

Comment: You're right, the whole problem is from my faulty normalization. I corrected  the typo on the post.

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to use complex numbers, do the following:
$$
f''+f=0\quad\Longrightarrow\quad f''+if'=i(f'+if),
$$ 
hence letting $g=f'+if$ we have that
$$
g'=ig\quad\Longrightarrow\quad\mathrm{e}^{-ix}(g'-ig)=0\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
\big(\mathrm{e}^{-ix}g\big)'=0\quad\Longrightarrow\quad g=c\,\mathrm{e}^{ix}.
$$
Thus
$$
f'+if=c\,\mathrm{e}^{ix}\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \mathrm{e}^{ix}(f'+if)=c\,\mathrm{e}^{2ix}
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \big(\mathrm{e}^{ix}f\big)=c\,\mathrm{e}^{2ix},
$$
and finally
$$
f=c\mathrm{e}^{ix}+c'\mathrm{e}^{-ix}=a\cos x+b\sin x.
$$

Comment: If I started from a strictly real-valued, real domain function, and proceeded with your method, does $f=ce^{ix}+c'e^{-x}$ guarantee a real result? In other words, where does the Imaginary part in the exponentials (i.e.: $i(c sinx+c' sinx$) vanish?

Comment: You do get a real valued function for suitable values of $c,c'\in\mathbb C$. In particular, if $c'=\bar c$, then $f$ is real-valued.